# How to access Chef metadata from a template

Tags: chef-infra

I can get the metadata via the [run_context](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/RunContext) object and for instance, write them to a file:

```
file '/etc/motd' do
  content "setup by [#{cookbook_name}] v#{run_context.cookbook_collection[cookbook_name].metadata.version}"
end
```

When I try to do the same in a template:

```
template 'etc/motd' do
  source 'default/motd.erb'
end
```

The motd.erb template file is as follows:

```
generated by <%= run_context.cookbook_collection['cookbook_name'].metadata.version %>
```

I've got a error because the run_context is not a method of [TemplateContext](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/Mixin/Template/TemplateContext):

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined local variable or method `run_context' for #<Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateContext:0x00000002c70c20>) on line #2:
```

TemplateContext does not seem to offer any way to retrieve the metadata. 
Is there a way to access to run_context from there ?

Comment: What about passing it through `variables` to the [template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html)? Not the direct way, but would solve it. Or do you know that already? :-)

Comment: @StephenKing I didn't know that since I started learning Chef yesterday. It is working fine. You can post this as a response. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can access it via `@node.run_context` but I really wouldn't do this. You are hitting about 5 different internal APIs, we make no promises this won't break on Chef upgrades.

Comment: Thank for the response and advice. Will carefully consider it before actually doing it. The idea was to create some sort of manifest from the metadata. Perhaps I need to cross the pet vs. cattle chasm first.